# updated_at in "timestamps" in Ecto always is inserted with a default value being ""now()"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've created a model in Ecto with "timestamps()". When I insert it:

```
changeset = Model1.changeset(%Model1{}, model1_params)
```

its "updated_at" automatically inserts too being equal to "inserted_at" or "now().

Even when I do this:

```
model1_params2 = Map.put(model1_params, "updated_at", nil)
```

it still inserts "updated_at" being equal to "inserted_at". How can I get it to insert "updated_at" with nil?

Comment: What is the use case for something like this?

Comment: My hunch is that you're using "nil", and the timestamps have a default that's set in the database. I checked the actual DB columns created by Phoenix and they come out to this. ----

 inserted_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null ----

If you use the :autogenerate option in https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1
you can customize the functionality of the fields.